# Search contains in a string column for a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

So I am using entity framework and linq, but I am using the function methods.

say I have a list of IDs like this:

```
List<string> bids = { "33", "44", "55", "66" }; // this is what the split ends up
```

But in the database, I have a string-column called "BuildingIDs" stored as comma-separated values. "query" is a IQueryable<BuildingTable>.

```
        List<string> bids = search_string_full_of_comma_bids.Split(';').ToList();
        query = query.Where(t => bids.Contains(t.BuildingIDs));
        //query = query.Any(t => t.BuildingIDs.Contains(bids); // Loop needed.
        return query;
```

So I want to search "BuildingIDs" database string **column**, to see if it has ANY of the "search_string_full_of_comma_bids"

BuildingTable in database:

```
project 1 | pname = 'building complex #1' | BuildingIDs = '33;54;42;56;21;56;32;'
project 2 | pname = 'building complex #2' | BuildingIDs = '77;42;31;12;33;'
```

But my search query could be "33" or "77" ... Searching "33" will deliver both. Searching "54;31" will deliver both as well.

So a standard SQL query would have been like:

```
SELECT * FROM BuildingTable WHERE BuildingIDs LIKE '%54%' OR BuildingIDs LIKE '%31%'.
```

Unfortunately I can't just add a bunch of "ORs" in Linq.

Comment: You should properly model your data in the DB. Sounds like you need a many-to-many table to match `ProjectID` to `BuildingID`.

Comment: Yes, but it's very very unlikely that there is more than 1-3 "buildings" per project, that's why it was string. And in some areas, you can only enter ONE building (one-to-many), but I need a catch all solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string> bids = search_string_full_of_comma_bids.Split(';').ToList();
        query = query.Where(t => bids.Any(b=> 
                               t.BuildingIDs.StartsWith (b+";") //if it's in the start
                              || t.BuildingIds.EndsWith (";" + b) //end 
                              || t.BuildngIds.Contains(";" + b + ";") //;id;
                              ));
```

You can try something like this, but this is ugly. You should have tables instead of saving Ids in a string.

Given your data you might not need the .EndsWith at all, usually you'll use that when the last one does not have ";" at the end.

Comment: This works great. Thank you. I should have tables if I aimed for scaling. I'm not. This situation will never have more than 3-5 "building ids" per field.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tim-s in that the data structure is the cause of the issue here, however, I created a [search extensions nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/) that can help with this. NinjaNye.SearchExtensions will enable you to something like the following:

```
using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions;
...
List<string> bids = search_string.Split(';').Select(b => ";" + b + ";");
query = query.Search(t => ";" + t.BuildingIDs + ";").Containing(bids)
```

This will return just the records that contain *any* of the supplied BuildingIDs